# ffmpeg H.264 Two-Pass runs fine on Windows but error on Linux (Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0)

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-encoding

the command I use to encode:

```
ffmpeg -y -i VideoCapture.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 444k -pass 1 -an -f null /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i VideoCapture.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 444k -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

I took this code from the official [ffmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass), by changing the audio and video bitrate values according to the examples in the [documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass). This code error when I run it on Linux.

The above code can run on windows (by changing the characters "NULL" and "").

This is the full output of the error:

```
ffmpeg version N-59498-g45dc668aea-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavcodec     59. 12.100 / 59. 12.100
  libavformat    59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 16.101 /  8. 16.101
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VideoCapture.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2021-07-02T07:26:53.000000Z
  Duration: 00:23:50.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 803 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 736 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-02T07:26:53.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-02T07:09:01.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x75dea80] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x75dea80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Why this happened? is there any solution for this problem?

thank you.